# Joint 3 tables in linq and return value of nested table with max id

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

I have there tables as you can see :

line:

```
id       Linename
1        line1
2        line2
3        line3
```

joint:

```
id       lineId   jointname
1        1        joint1
2        2        joint2
3        1        joint3
```

fitup:

```
id      jointid    fitupdate     state
1       1          2012/12/12    acc
2       1          2013/12/12    rej
3       2          2015/12/12    acc
4       2          2016/12/12    rej
```

Result i need:

```
id     Linename      jointname    fitupdate     state
1      line1          joint1      2013/12/12    rej
2      line2          joint2      2016/12/12    rej
```

The fitup table has a `state` I need the final state based on max id.

In the fitup table i have multi rows for each joint but i need the date(string) of max id in the result query .

Here is my query:

```
var q = from j in _ctx.Joints
    join l in _ctx.Lines on j.LineId equals l.Id
    join spo in _ctx.Spools on j.SpoolId equals spo.Id
    join sup in _ctx.Supports on j.SupportId equals sup.Id
    join shee in _ctx.Sheets on j.SheetId equals shee.Id
    join Fit in _ctx.FitUpDetails on j.Id equals Fit.JointId into g2
    from y2 in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()

    join weld in _ctx.WeldDetails on j.Id equals weld.JointId into g
    from y1 in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join end in _ctx.Ends on j.EndId equals end.Id

    join basemat in _ctx.BaseMaterials on j.BaseMaterialId equals basemat.Id
    join TestPack in _ctx.TestPackages on j.TestPackageId equals TestPack.Id

    group new { j, l,y2,y1} by new { shee, j, l, spo, sup, y2, y1, end, basemat, TestPack } into grouping
    let maxFitById = grouping.Select(item => item.y2)
                     .Where(item => item != null)
                     .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

    let maxweldById = grouping.Select(item => item.y1)
   .Where(item => item != null)
   .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)

    select new ViewFront()
    {
        Id = grouping.Key.j.Id,
        LineId = grouping.Key.l.LineNumber,
        SubmitDateTime = grouping.Key.j.SubmitDateTime,
        JointNumber = grouping.Key.j.JointNumber,
        BaseMaterialId = grouping.Key.basemat.Name,
        FitUpAccept = maxFitById.FirstOrDefault().StateStep1,
        FitUpAcceptMain = maxFitById.FirstOrDefault().StateStep2,
        JointClass = grouping.Key.j.JointClass,
        End = grouping.Key.end.Name,
        JointSize = grouping.Key.j.JointSize,
        LeftMaterialItemCode = grouping.Key.j.LeftMaterialItemCode,
        LeftMaterialLength = grouping.Key.j.LeftMaterialLength.ToString(),
        MagneticTest = grouping.Key.j.MagneticTest,
        PenetrationTest = grouping.Key.j.PenetrationTest,
        PostWeldHeatTreatment = grouping.Key.j.PostWeldHeatTreatment,
        RemarkState = grouping.Key.j.RemarkState,
        RightMaterialItemCode = grouping.Key.j.RightMaterialItemCode,
        RightMaterialLength = grouping.Key.j.RightMaterialLength.ToString(),
        RadiographyTest = grouping.Key.j.RadiographyTest,
        SheetId = grouping.Key.shee.SheetNumber,
        ShopField = grouping.Key.j.ShopField,
        SpoolId = grouping.Key.spo.SpoolNumber,
        SupportId = grouping.Key.sup.SupportNumber,
        TestPackageId = grouping.Key.TestPack.PackageNumber,
        THK = grouping.Key.j.THK,
        UltrasonicTest = grouping.Key.j.UltrasonicTest,
        WeldAccept = maxweldById.FirstOrDefault().StateStep1,
        WeldAcceptMain = maxweldById.FirstOrDefault().StateStep2
    };
```

In this query `FitUpAccept` is the state .

Joint table data 
[image]

weld :
[image]

fitup:
[image]

result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what you need. Now some explanations:

1. I kept only the tables relevant for the described output data just to keep it simpler.
2. When `grouping by` - If you select the entire objects as you did then you will always get "groups" of a single record - I `group` the wanted data just by the `key` - In this case the non aggregated fields. Make sure that you are not grouping by the same fields that you want to actually do aggregation operations by them ( like y2 )
3. Because it is a `left join` to the `FitUpDetails` I must make sure that I remove all the `null` records and whenever I access a property of that object to make sure it is not null - c# 6.0 syntax of `?.`.
4. Now for the *By max id* part - if I put it into words: "Grouping the data by X, and then for each group ordering it by Y, take first record -> its properties"

So to the code:

```
var result = (from j in Joints
              join l in Lines on j.LineId equals l.Id
              join f in FitUpDetails on j.Id equals f.JointId into g2
              from y2 in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()

              group new { j, l, y2 } by new { j.Id, l.LineName, j.JointName } into grouping

              let maxFitById = grouping.Select(item => item.y2)
                                      .Where(item => item != null)
                                      .OrderByDescending(item => item.Id)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()

              select new
              {
                  Id = grouping.Key.Id,
                  LineName = grouping.Key.LineName,
                  JointName = grouping.Key.JointName,
                  FitUpdate = maxFitById?.FitUpdate,
                  State = maxFitById?.State
              }).ToList();
```

Used this for testing it:

```
List<dynamic> Joints = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1, LineId = 1, JointName = "joint1" },
    new { Id = 2, LineId = 2, JointName = "joint2" },
    new { Id = 3, LineId = 1, JointName = "joint3" },
};

List<dynamic> Lines = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1, LineName = "line1" },
    new { Id = 2, LineName = "line2" },
    new { Id = 3, LineName = "line3" },
};

List<dynamic> FitUpDetails = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Id = 1, JointId = 1, FitUpdate = new DateTime(2012,12,12), State = "acc" },
    new { Id = 2, JointId = 1, FitUpdate = new DateTime(2013,12,12), State = "rej" },
    new { Id = 1, JointId = 2, FitUpdate = new DateTime(2015,12,12), State = "acc" },
    new { Id = 4, JointId = 2, FitUpdate = new DateTime(2016,12,12), State = "rej" },
};
```

Comment: The problem is here: `new { shee, j, l, spo, sup, y2, y1, end,` - if you group by the `y2` it means that you will have for each record in the FitUpdate table a different group - so when you order by you only have one record - and your result will show both the "acc" and "reg"

Comment: Thank you very very much dear friend

Comment: @Also - see that I edited my answer and moved the `FirstOrDefault` to the `let` - makes the `select` a bit cleaner

Comment: Hi again,i have some problem here could you please take a look :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929024/grouping-in-entityframework-shows-3-records-instead-of-1-record